# Symfony2: Warning: spl_object_hash() expects parameter 1 to be object, integer given

Tags: php, symfony, insert, one-to-many

I have a many to one relationship between the entities **Project** and **Course** because each course can have many projects so many projects could be related to the same course.

These are my entities:

```
class Project{

    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    //... other fields ...


    //----------------------- DATABASE RELATIONSHIP ----------------//

    //PROJECT-COURSE - M:1 relationship
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Course", inversedBy="project")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="course_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     **/
    private  $course;
```

and

```
class Course{

    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */

    //... other fields ...

    //----------------------- DATABASE RELATIONSHIP----------------//

    //COURSE-PROJECT 1:M relationship
    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Project", mappedBy="course")
     **/
    private $project;
```

The error appears when i try to insert a new project for my course, this is my form builder:

```
            $builder
                ->add('name', 'text', array(
                    'attr' => array('class' => 'form-control')))
                ->add('description', 'textarea', array(
                    'attr' => array('class' => 'form-control', 'rows' => '10')))
                ->add('submit', 'submit', array(
                    'attr' => array('class' => 'btn btn-primary')));
```

I try to insert these data creating a Project object and filling it with the result of the form as you can see:

```
$project->setName($form->get('name')->getData());
                $project->setDescription($form->get('description')->getData());
                $project->setPhasesNumber($form->get('phases_number')->getData());
                $project->setPathNumber($form->get('path_number')->getData());
                $project->setYear(date('Y'));
                $project->setCourse(5); //number 5 is just a test

                $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
                $em->persist($project);
                $em->flush();
```

The problem should be related to the command `$project->setCourse(5);` and I've seen that if i remove the relationship between Project and Course the bug doesn't appear. The bug disappears even if I comment the line used to set the course id, so I think I have a problem with this relationship but I can't understand where.

I've just read other question like this on stackoverflow but it doesn't help me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's looking for you to use an object with an instance of `Course`. Just passing the ID of the course does not work.

You could do:

```
//...
$course = $this->getDoctrine()
               ->getManager()
               ->getRepository('Namespace:Course')
               ->findOneById(5);
$project->setCourse($course);
//...
```

As @Full mentions if you know that the entity already exists you can just set it without a DB lookup by doing:

```
$project->setCourse($this->getDoctrine()
                         ->getManager()
                         ->getReference('Namespace:Course', 5)
);
```

Comment: Took me several hours to get to this point, and your solution was really helpful. Thanks

Comment: Actually it would be better to use
`$this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->getReference('Namespace:Course', 5);`
without searching in db!