# Warning: spl_object_hash() expects parameter 1 to be object when i persist my data

Tags: symfony, doctrine

i'm trying to add my data into my database , i was trying to not use a formbuilder, inside that i put all my form into the controller,and my entity contains a foreign key but i got an this error :
Warning: spl_object_hash() expects parameter 1 to be object, integer given in C:\wamp\www\HelloWordExemple\vendor\doctrine\orm\lib\Doctrine\ORM\UnitOfWork.php line 1602

here is my function

```
 public function AjoutAction(Request $request)
{   $classe=new Etudiant();
$formBuilder = $this->get('form.factory')->createBuilder('form', $classe);    
$formBuilder
  ->add('prenom', 'text')
  ->add('nom', 'text')
  ->add('Cin', 'integer')
  ->add('id_classe', 'integer')
  ->add('save',      'submit')
;
$form = $formBuilder->getForm();
if ($form->handleRequest($request)->isValid()) {
    $objToPersist = $form->getData();
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $em->persist($objToPersist);
    $em->flush();
 } 
 return $this->render('MyAppSchoolBundle:Etudiant:ajout.html.twig',array(
    'form' => $form->createView(),
 ));  
 }
```

here is my entity

```
  namespace MyApp\SchoolBundle\Entity;
 use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
 use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
 use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntity;

   /**
    * @ORM\Entity
    */
    class Etudiant {

   /**
    * @ORM\id
    *@ORM\GeneratedValue
    *@ORM\Column(type="integer",name="ID_Etudiant")   
    */
private $Id;
/**
 *@ORM\Column{type="string",length=255}
 */
private $prenom;
/**
 *@ORM\Column{type="string",length=255}
 */

private $nom;
/**
 *@Assert\NotBlank
 *@ORM\Column(type="integer", unique=true)
 */

private $cin; //unique ne fonctionne pas qu'avec les assert
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Classes",cascade={"ALL"})
 */
private $idClasse;
function getId() {
    return $this->Id;
}

function getPrenom() {
    return $this->prenom;
}

public function getNom() {
    return $this->nom;
}

public function setId($Id) {
    $this->Id = $Id;
}

public function setPrenom($prenom) {
    $this->prenom = $prenom;
}

public function setNom($nom) {
    $this->nom = $nom;
}

public function getCin() {
    return $this->cin;
}

public function setCin($cin) {
    $this->cin = $cin;
}
function getIdClasse() {
    return $this->idClasse;
}

function setIdClasse($idClasse) {
    $this->idClasse = $idClasse;
}



}
```

any one have an idea please??

Comment: the attribute `id_classe` in the form can't be an integer, you must define it as `Entity` (in the form definition). PS:  are you setting the numeric id in the form filed?

Comment: possible duplicate: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26664890/symfony2-warning-spl-object-hash-expects-parameter-1-to-be-object-integer-g 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14727497/warning-spl-object-hash-expects-parameter-1-to-be-object-with-message

Answer (score 1):

As the Matteo said id_classe has to be object not ant integer. Please read the [documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html) about entity field type.